# Python - Selenium - Looking for recommendations on how to verify the contents of a table

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a table that I am able to iterate through and print out the contents of each cell.  What I am looking for now is a suggestion on how to verify the contents of each of the cells.  Assume the table is 10 columns X 20 rows.

Here's code for iterating through the table and printing out the contents of each cell:

```
table_id = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='clientTable']/div/div[6]/div/div/div/div/table")
    rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
        for col in cols:
            print(col.text)
```

Comment: You need to know the expected value or pattern of text in the table.

Answer (score 0):

As dogstar suggested, you need to know the contents of the table.

Then just do something like `assert <text> in col.text`, using an assert library of your choice.